# Hazelcast using Transaction with C# Client and propagating to Sql Server

Tags: c#, transactions, hazelcast

Using the [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/) IMDG using C#.Net, which has lot of interesting Data structures to suit various use cases, It does support transactions in Java as detailed in this [link](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#creating-a-transaction-interface).

Not able to find any reference regarding C#, therefore wanted to understand:

1. Does C# client support Transactions ?
2. If Yes, then does transaction propagate support to external system like Sql Server
3. If No, what are the other strategies, Compensating Transaction, Write Behind, which are supported by HazelCast

Comment: Down-Voter, which part you couldn't understand, at least provide a response to befit the down-vote

Comment: @Saruman thanks will post in other groups too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast .Net Client support transactions with a similar API to Java.
You can see the [API doc](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/clients/net/3.9.4/html/G_Hazelcast_Client.htm)

1. Hazelcast .Net Client does support transactions.
2. Unfortunately there is no two phase transaction or XA support so that you cannot propagate the transaction to Sql server.
3. Hazelcast does not have a builtin support for Compensating Transactions.

Comment: thanks for the details, does Hazelcast support a write behind strategy, through I can make a change to Cache flow into external system, even if its not part of a transaction

Comment: @MrinalKamboj; `IMap` supports write-behind persistence, when enabled changes to in-memory data are reflected to external system in batches. See [Setting Write-Behind Persistence](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.6/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-write-behind-persistence)